# Google Play App Signing and Instant Apps

Tags: android, google-play, android-instant-apps, android-app-signing

Fairly straight forward question. Does anyone happen to know if Google Play App Signing supports Instant Apps? The reason I ask:

> Enter your app’s signing config, or select a keystore file. While it’s possible to use a debug config or keystore during testing, the generated Digital Asset Links file won’t be compatible with the release version of your app. If you do upload a Digital Asset Links file that uses a debug config or keystore, then before publishing your app you’ll need to generate and upload a new Digital Asset Links that uses your app’s release key.

From Blog post:- [How to Create an Instant App Feature](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-instant-app-feature--cms-29298)

If this claim is true, does the play console provide a means for generating a `assetlinks.json`? This is the file that you must host on the domain you are claiming to be affiliated with.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, Google Play App Signing supports Instant Apps. You will use your Signing key instead of the Upload key because Google Play will re-sign your app with the signing key.

Android Studio provides a way to generate the assetlinks.json, just go to `Tools > App Links Assistant > Associate Website`, then you can select the  correct keystore file.

- [Add Android App Links > Associate your app with your website](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/app-link-indexing.html#associatesite)

You can also manually do it through the [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator)

Other posts have also addressed this

- [Digital Asset Link verified by Android Studio, but not pass in Google Play Console](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46037099/digital-asset-link-verified-by-android-studio-but-not-pass-in-google-play-conso/46138747#46138747)
- [Instant App - Digital Asset Links Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723755/instant-app-digital-asset-links-protocol/45884163#45884163)