# ANDROID DEEPLINKS: Is there a way to easily create a permission such that old & new versions of the app can simultaneously deeplink into the website?

Tags: android, hybrid-mobile-app, deep-linking, applinks, android-deep-link

I want to know if there's a fool-proof-automatic/easy way to create a website permission that will allow old and new versions of an android mobile application to deeplink into the website simultaneously?

**My dilemma:**
Every time I create a new .apk, a new *sha256-cert fingerprint* is produced. Therefore, it goes without saying that I gotta create a new [assetlinks.json](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/v1/getting-started) and upload it into the website's *.well-known* folder so that my app can get a permission to deeplink into it. As a result, old versions of the app can no longer deeplink :(

**Reason for asking:**
I wanna make everyone's lives easier by skipping that tedious process or make the process friendlier and on top of that, allow clients who got old versions of the app to deeplink into the website as well :)

Comment: I was under the impression that old versions can work as long as the keystore remains the same: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#web-assoc or are you using [Google Play App Signing and Instant Apps](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46488635/295004)

Comment: Hi Morrison! Yes, it works. I asked the wrong question. I guess, what I really want to know is if I can use two applications using one permission. For example, App1 can deeplink into the website while app2 is also Dee-linking it. App1 and App2 are different applications.

Comment: [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55252928/edit) your question so that it is correct. Again list what resources you check and explain why [Associating a website with multiple apps](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/verify-site-associations#multiple-apps) doesn't answer your question.

Comment: Thank you for spoon-feeding me, Morrison! That's what I need right now, you helped me big-time!

Comment: Actually, I'll just leave it like that (the question). You answered two questions of mine today and as a tech-greenhorn who's a newb in programming, you made me really grateful! I will be able to sleep well tonight! Thanks A LOT!