# how to link website with digital asset link protocol for Instant app?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps

I am stuck from last one week, i am not able to upload instant app apk.
I am getitng "Your site 'sptechinfo.000webhostapp.com' has not been linked through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app. Please link your site through the Digital Assets Link protocol to your app"

I already added assetlink.json [AssetLink.json](https://sptechinfo.000webhostapp.com/.well-known/assetlinks.json) but still am gettign same error on playstore.

I verified link from here  https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=http://sptechinfo.000webhostapp.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls
but getting same error.

this is my asset_statements in string.xml file
 [{\n  \"relation\": [\"delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls\"],\n  \"target\": {\n    \"namespace\": \"web\",\n    \"site\": \"http://sptechinfo.000webhostapp.com\",\n  }\n}]

Please anyone help me to solve this.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723755/instant-app-digital-asset-links-protocol

Comment: Thanks brother,

its small mistake i need to used SHA 256 from playstore console not from keystore.

Comment: welcome sir i will posted answer related to it this helps u and other people

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ref : [Instant App - Digital Asset Links Protocol](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44723755/instant-app-digital-asset-links-protocol)

This happened to me when I had generated an assetlinks.json file from my debug keys, rather than the release keys. It shows up as verified in Android Studio, then fails on the server. Double check that the signing config is correct for your asset links file, and that the fingerprint in the file matches the SHA256 fingerprint of your release key. You can get your release key's fingerprint by running

```
keytool -list -v -keystore ~/my_keystore.jks
```

Another cause can be if you've enabled Play signing. In that case, you have to use the fingerprint provided in your developer console, not the one for the key you signed the APK with locally (the local one is called your "upload key"). This isn't obvious in Android Studio at all, since its asset link file generator doesn't give you an option to put in a custom fingerprint.